# Cloning another user's github repository into Eclipse workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I cloned an Android project from another user's github repository into my workspace folder. However, the Package Explorer in Eclipse cannot find it.

Through Eclipse, I tried importing the project into the workspace:

> Import->Android->Existing Android Code into Workspace

Unfortunately, Eclipse does not see it as a project. I cannot import it.

How do I import a cloned Android repository into the Eclipse workspace?

Answer (score 0):

try to import the project as a import->android->Existing Android Code into Workspace

Comment: This is what I used and it does not see the project as an Android project. It is. And I find it strange not working.

Comment: did you tried to import it as a general project? import -> general -> Existing Projects into Workspace

Comment: The same result. I tried importing inside and outside the workspace, the error it gives me "No projects are found to import"

Answer (score 0):

I've never cloned directly to my workspace, issue could be that it want let you import it since it's already existing in the workspace. Try cloning to another location, maybe your My Docs folder then import it from there into your workspace. Be sure to delete the existing one that resides in your workspace first.

If you want, try using a git gui such as: http://nathanj.github.io/gitguide/tour.html.

This is helpful for those that aren't familiar with how to clone repos, not to mention its easy to use.